# How to configure language negotiation in apache

Tags: html, apache

I want to serve different files with apache depending on the preferred language setting in the users browser. I.e the "Accept-Language" key in the request header.

I follow [this description](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-apache-lang-neg) and I put

```
Options +MultiViews                                                   
AddLanguage de .de                                                              
AddLanguage en .en                                                              
AddLanguage es .es                                                              
LanguagePriority en de es                                                       
ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
```

in my apache2.conf and generated the files `index.html`, `index.html.en` and `index.html.es`. I also tried index.en.html etc.

The problem is:

Regardless of what I set in the browser (or what I specify in the header using `curl`), I always get the `index.html`

I *did* restart apache an I *did* empty the browser cache.

I use apache 2.4.10 on a debian jessie system.

**How do I get apache to serve the correct files according to the `Accept-Language` header?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using the module Rewrite (mod_rewrite) and just redirect user's to specific pages based on the Accepted-Language passed by the browser.

In your configuration file you can add something into the `<Directory></Directory>` tag or just in the middle of the `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` tags to do the redirection for you.

Since you have supplied German, English, and Spanish in your example you can add the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://your-site.com/index.html.de [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://your-site.com/index.html.es [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://your-site.com/index.html.en [L,R=301]
```

However, if you wish to continue with the method in your question. You must first make sure mod_negotiation is loaded in your HTTPD.CONF file.

You also must not include a literal **index.html** file but tell your site to look for one.

So it will look something like this

```
<Directory "/your/directory/path">
  Options +MultiViews 
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  AddLanguage de .de                                                
  AddLanguage en .en                                                              
  AddLanguage es .es                                                              
  LanguagePriority en de es                                                       
  ForceLanguagePriority Fallback  
</Directory>
```

Then for your index files just make sure index.html.en, index.html.de, and index.html.es exist.

This will work since Apache will then look at the **DirectoryIndex** directive and will search for **index.html**. However, since index.html does not exist the MultiViews option will try to find the closest option to best serve the user's request. So if the user has the option English as there preference, it will load index.html.en

Comment: renaming `index.html` to `index.html.de` did the trick, thank you! Please elaborate on the advantages of using `mod_rewrite` instead of `mod_negotiation`

Comment: _Grazie!_ Your `<Directory>` block was all I needed; I didn't need to use rewrites.

Comment: How do you make a literal `index.html` file be the default language (say, English)? Why does including the literal `index.html` in your example break it?